# Pentaho ETL performance issues

Tags: performance, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I have a Pentaho ETL Job/Transformation that reads a text file and inserts some records into a MS SQL Database table. 
I execute it daily. It take up to 10 minutes to  finish. The problem happens when someone else executes it: the time rises up to 40 minutes.
All the exections happens on the same machine, with the same JRE version.
The logs don't show nothing unusual, just a greater time lapse between the steps.

**System info:**

- Windows 8 Enterprise 64bits
- JRE 1.7_79 32 bits
- Pentaho 5.3.0
- MS SQL 2000 (8.0)

Called command:

```
C:\SR\bin\data-integration>"C:\SR\bin\jre1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe"  "-Xmx512m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "-Djava.library.path=libswt\win32" "-DKETTLE_HOME=" "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=" "-DKETTLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=" "-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=" "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=" -jar launcher\pentaho-application-launcher-5.3.0.0-213.jar -lib ..\libswt\win32  -main org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen /file C:\SR\config\pentaho\visao.kjb /param:"dia=29" /param:"mes=09" /param:"ano=2016" /param:"arquivo=Realize2016" /param:"dia_util=28" /norep
```

**My log:**

```
2016/09/27 11:26:03 - Reading of file MyFile.0 - Line number : 50000
2016/09/27 11:26:03 - Validate Records.0 - Linenr 50000
2016/09/27 11:26:03 - Discarded records.0 - Linenr 50000
2016/09/27 11:26:04 - Reading of file MyFile.0 - Line number : 100000
2016/09/27 11:26:04 - Validate Records.0 - Linenr 100000
2016/09/27 11:26:04 - Discarded records.0 - Linenr 100000
2016/09/27 11:26:05 - Reading of file MyFile.0 - Line number : 150000
2016/09/27 11:26:05 - Validate Records.0 - Linenr 150000
2016/09/27 11:26:05 - Discarded records.0 - Linenr 150000
2016/09/27 11:26:06 - Reading of file MyFile.0 - Line number : 200000
2016/09/27 11:26:06 - Validate Records.0 - Linenr 200000
2016/09/27 11:26:06 - Discarded records.0 - Linenr 200000
2016/09/27 11:26:07 - Reading of file MyFile.0 - Line number : 250000
2016/09/27 11:26:07 - Validate Records.0 - Linenr 250000
2016/09/27 11:26:08 - Discarded records.0 - Linenr 250000
```

**My colleague log:**

```
2016/09/29 10:13:26 - Reading of file MyFile.0 - Line number : 50000
2016/09/29 10:13:32 - Validate Records.0 - Linenr 50000
2016/09/29 10:13:32 - Discarded records.0 - Linenr 50000
2016/09/29 10:13:40 - Reading of file MyFile.0 - Line number : 100000
2016/09/29 10:13:46 - Validate Records.0 - Linenr 100000
2016/09/29 10:13:47 - Discarded records.0 - Linenr 100000
2016/09/29 10:13:56 - Reading of file MyFile.0 - Line number : 150000
2016/09/29 10:14:01 - Validate Records.0 - Linenr 150000
2016/09/29 10:14:02 - Discarded records.0 - Linenr 150000
2016/09/29 10:14:10 - Reading of file MyFile.0 - Line number : 200000
2016/09/29 10:14:17 - Validate Records.0 - Linenr 200000
2016/09/29 10:14:18 - Discarded records.0 - Linenr 200000
2016/09/29 10:14:26 - Reading of file MyFile.0 - Line number : 250000
2016/09/29 10:14:31 - Validate Records.0 - Linenr 250000
2016/09/29 10:14:32 - Discarded records.0 - Linenr 250000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what was causing the poor performance during the execution of the Job by my co-worker.

After comparing all the enviroments variables and configurations, his profile was missing some Kettle/Pentaho config files.
These files were created by Spoon and my colleague has never executed Spoon. He only run the Job using Kitchen.

The files were created in %USERPROFILE%\.kettle\

Another difference between my profile and his, was the default location set on Spoon. Mine was set to en-US, while his was using the system default (pt-BR).

After all settings were the same between the profiles, the execution time decreased significantly: from 40 minutes (average) to 6 minutes (average).

Answer (score 1):

There's got to be something different. Are you executing on the same account? In what env? Windows or Linux?

Have you tried executing using pan/kitchen? Perhaps it will standardize your environments?

If you upload the trasformation etc I'll take a look.

Comment: Using Windows 8 Enterprise (64 bits). Different accounts. Same env. Already checked system and user vars.

Comment: My suggestion in that case would be to create a new account for running things that everyone can use. Test it with that. Who knows what he's got set up on his account. Even though things may be the same perhaps he has some random java configuration tuning the JVM that's affecting something low level. Heaps set differently? (shot in the dark there) Or vice versa and you've turbo charged it.

Like I was saying if it's possible to try running with CLI pan/kitchen it might standardize your environments a little. I don't have experience calling kitchen via the class but that's what I would do.

Comment: I'm using kitchen to execute the job. Calling it throught a bat script. I cannot create another account just to execute it (company policies - each account is bound to an employee), I'm using a distinct JRE just to run it (the system JRE is in a different path). Both accounts use the same JRE to run kitchen.

Comment: Ah. Great old company policies. :)

Comment: Ah. Great old company policies. :)

Then my suggestion would be to start overriding more and more of the defaults on the commandline. Something has gotta be different from his JRE to your's (like the heaps etc). There's a lot more that you can configure besides the memory and the garbage collection. Though this is shot in the dark stuff on my part without being able to look and monitor it your resources while it's running.

Have you randomly tried on other people's environments to find out which one of you is the outlier?

Also try the new pentaho? It's, IMHO, considerably better.

Comment: Have u looked on Task Manager during execution, CPU, MEMORY, and NETWORK?